# Delete a image, and delete from Image viewer under Win 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm using an pictue, first load the picture to a image control in xaml:

```
<Image Name="pic" Height="550" Width="400"  Source="{Binding img}"  Stretch="Fill"/>
```

After loading to image, i want delete the source file, and also delete from teh image control.

Button click:

```
pic.Source = null;   
StorageFile sf = null;
StorageFolder sd = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
sf = await sd.GetItemAsync("imgs\\img") as StorageFile;
await sf.DeleteAsync();
```

But :Access Denied.

I use this:

```
pic.Source = null;
```

but same problem. How can i delete the image ?

Thans for all reply!

Comment: What is the `img` property you're binding to from XAML?

Comment: Are you certain that you are not referencing the image in another control?

Comment: Firstly, try using SetSource. Secondly, can you just set the Visibility collapsed? With regards to the Access Denied issue, you may need to investigate if the file is still in use at the time that you are trying to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:Impossible in this format, but this solved this problem:

```
RandomAccessStreamReference rs= RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(path));
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        var rstream = await rs.OpenReadAsync();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(rstream);
        pic.Source = bi;
```

Image must be load to stream, and after the file can be delete.